# Why is my background svg not changing when I toggle/add another class with a other background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, background-image

I have a div with a svg background + animation. I added a button and said that a class should get toggled / added and removed when i click on it, so that the *"background-image"* would change. But it isn't working. Maybe it is a fault in my jquery, but i actually don't know at all.

Here is my code:

My css code with the full svg codes (--> u can't post more then 30.000 charakters lol): http://pastebin.com/Qwys2tpZ

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.Space-Container {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,..... - svg code here - .......);
}

.Space-Container-2 {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,..... - svg code here - .......)   !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Space</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Space.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".start").click(function () {
          $("#Img").removeClass("Space-Container");
          $("#Img").addClass("Space-Container-2");
        });
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <button class="start">start</button>
    
    <div id="Img" class="Space-Container">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't appear to be with your jQuery. There could be something going on in the SVG code itself in Space-container-2. However, without knowing more about the specific problem you're seeing, I would suggest giving your Img div a specific width and height, and applying the same properties to .Space-container-2 as you have in .Space-container:

```
.Space-Container-2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,..... - svg code here - .......);
}
```

Otherwise, when you remove the .Space-container class you're removing all styling for that element, including its width and height.

Answer (score 2):

Your class .Space-Container-2 should have the rest of the properties that you have specified in .Space-Container. You are setting the width and height ( at least in this example ) in Space-Container. Then you are removing the class. So when you add the new class you need to set it back